# Transition not working on input type submit using CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two buttons `Let’s Go!` and `click me`. One is `input type submit` and second is an `anchor tag`.
Transition of the `anchor tag` is working when the user clicks on it but `input type submit` isn't working if clicked.

Check the script bellow. Also is there any other easy ways to solve this?

```js
const isMobile = window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/) && window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/)[0] === "Mobile";
const event = isMobile ? "touchstart" : "click";
const button = document.querySelectorAll('*[data-animation="ripple"]'),
  container = document.querySelector(".container");
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  const currentBtn = button[i];
  currentBtn.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const button = e.target,
      rect = button.getBoundingClientRect(),
      originalBtn = this,
      btnHeight = rect.height,
      btnWidth = rect.width;
    let posMouseX = 0,
      posMouseY = 0;
    if (isMobile) {
      posMouseX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - rect.left;
      posMouseY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - rect.top;
    } else {
      posMouseX = e.x - rect.left;
      posMouseY = e.y - rect.top;
    }
    const baseCSS = `position: absolute;
     width: ${btnWidth * 2}px;
      height: ${btnWidth * 2}px;
      transition: all linear 700ms;
     transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);border-radius: 50%;
     background: var(--color-ripple);
    top:${posMouseY - btnWidth}px;
    left:${posMouseX - btnWidth}px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform:scale(0)`

    var rippleEffect = document.createElement("span");
    rippleEffect.style.cssText = baseCSS;

    //prepare the dom
    currentBtn.style.overflow = "hidden";
    this.appendChild(rippleEffect);

    //start animation
    setTimeout(function() {
      rippleEffect.style.cssText = baseCSS + `transform:scale(1); opacity: 0;`;
    }, 5);

    setTimeout(function() {
      rippleEffect.remove();
      //window.location.href = currentBtn.href;
    }, 700);
  })
}
```

```css
:root {
  /* if u want to change the color of
  * the ripple change this value
 */
  --color-ripple: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"] {
  position: relative;
  /*Position relative is required*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #e570e7 0%, #79f1fc 100%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 14px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 50px;*/
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"]::selection {
  background: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a data-animation="ripple">Click Me</a>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="searchbtrn" value="Let’s Go!" data-animation="ripple" width=100>
```

Comment: It's because you cannot `appendChild` to an `input`. Therefore the logic you're using for the effect won't work on inline elements (eg `input`, `img`)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Where should I change it?

Comment: It's not a simple change - you would need to complete rethink how this works.

Comment: You could replace the `input` by a `button`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, the reason why it's not working is because you're trying to append an element to an `input`, which can't be done.

One solution would be to replace the `input` by a `button`, but you also stated that you don't want to do that.

The only other solution that I can think of would be to wrap your `input` with a `span` and append the ripple to this span. After the effect is done, unwrap the `input`. I've done this in the example below.

```js
const isMobile = window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/) && window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/)[0] === "Mobile";
const event = isMobile ? "touchstart" : "click";
const button = document.querySelectorAll('*[data-animation="ripple"]'),
  container = document.querySelector(".container");
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  const currentBtn = button[i];
  currentBtn.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const button = e.target,
      rect = button.getBoundingClientRect(),
      originalBtn = this,
      btnHeight = rect.height,
      btnWidth = rect.width;
    let posMouseX = 0,
      posMouseY = 0;
    if (isMobile) {
      posMouseX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - rect.left;
      posMouseY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - rect.top;
    } else {
      posMouseX = e.x - rect.left;
      posMouseY = e.y - rect.top;
    }
    const baseCSS = `position: absolute;
     width: ${btnWidth * 2}px;
      height: ${btnWidth * 2}px;
      transition: all linear 700ms;
     transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);border-radius: 50%;
     background: var(--color-ripple);
    top:${posMouseY - btnWidth}px;
    left:${posMouseX - btnWidth}px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform:scale(0)`;

    var rippleEffect = document.createElement("span");
    rippleEffect.style.cssText = baseCSS;

    //prepare the dom
    currentBtn.style.overflow = "hidden";
    var btn = this;
    if (btn.tagName === "INPUT") {
      $(btn).wrap('<span class="ripple-wrap"></span>').after(rippleEffect);
    }
    else {
      btn.appendChild(rippleEffect);
    }

    //start animation
    setTimeout(function() {
      rippleEffect.style.cssText = baseCSS + `transform:scale(1); opacity: 0;`;
    }, 5);

    setTimeout(function() {
      rippleEffect.remove();
      if (btn.tagName === "INPUT") {
        $(btn).unwrap();
      }
      //window.location.href = currentBtn.href;
    }, 700);
  })
}
```

```css
:root {
  /* if u want to change the color of
  * the ripple change this value
 */
  --color-ripple: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"] {
  position: relative;
  /*Position relative is required*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #e570e7 0%, #79f1fc 100%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 14px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 50px;*/
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"]::selection {
  background: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.ripple-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a data-animation="ripple">Click Me</a>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="searchbtrn" value="Let’s Go!" data-animation="ripple" width=100>
```

Comment: It's perfectly working for me.Thanks for your help. Upvote from my side

Answer (score 1):

You can used `button` tag for this try below

```
<button type="submit" name="searchbtrn" data-animation="ripple">Let's Go!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Button will work but I don't need the button. In want to use input type

Comment: But button working as same type of submit input. You make anything then please replay here i will solve this.

Comment: Can we make the transition with the help of CSS?

Comment: But for this trasition must include one element between input tag, and input tag not support close tab so it's not possible